# i want to make a combobox that will detect if the existing data is in Database Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, scheduling

Here is a clear explanation i want to create a ComboBox that will automatically remove all the data in the comboBox that is Existing in the database

example in my Combobox there's a data 
7:00 - 8:00
8:30 - 9:00
9:30 - 10:00

and in my database there are existing 7:00- 8:00 record

what i want is the 7:00 - 8:00 data that is existing in the database will be remove in my comboBox thankyou so much

Comment: ***How are you loading data***?

Comment: i just manually add all the data in the combobox edit items :P :)

Comment: Ok, so in what case and or event do you want to search the db and remove existing records? IMO use a textbox and then search db, if record exist remove it.

Comment: actually sir what i want is when the form load they will check my Database and check the LectureTime if there are some data detected in my database that data will be remove automatically in my ComboBox

Comment: If thats the case, load your data from the db. Then it will reflect what is there. Doing the opposite doesnt make sense since this is what you would be doing anyways... Then you can bind the good data with your combobox.

Comment: To be honest .. it is very simple to achieve mate :)

Comment: The main reason that people have trouble solving problems like this is that they're trying to solve the wrong problem. This issue has nothing to do with a `ComboBox`. A `ComboBox` simply displays a list of data. If you don't a data item displayed then don't include it in the list. That happens before the `ComboBox` comes into play at all. You might be sending that list anywhere but how you narrow down the list to only the items of interest won't change.

Comment: Basically, you start with a list of all possible data items in some form. What form that takes is up to you. For each item in that list, you then test whether that item exists in the database. There are two main options there: get all the data from the database into a list and test that or query the database for each item. The better option depends on how much data there is. If you find a match then you exclude that item from the original list. Once you've done that for each original item, you populate the `ComboBox` or whatever with the remaining items. You can make an attempt at that.